# Need a way to handle & character in URL on button click java script

Tags: url, urlhacking

I have custom button on lead object which on click of the button it opens custom URL with some prepopulated fields from lead object. Its behavior and content both are Java script i wants to do some validations thats why i have taken content source as java script and not URL.

Now some of the lead fields that i m prepopulationg has '**&'** character in it's value when URL gets generated that time it causes an issue and says Invalid Identifier. 
Please suggest a way to resolve this error. PFB my code on button click.

```
var LeadIdValue="{!Lead.Id}"
var NameValue="{!Lead.Name}"
var MailValue="{!Lead.Email}"
var CompanyValue="{!Lead.Company}"
var sInterest="{!Lead.Secondary_Product_Interests__c}"
var pInterest="{!Lead.Primary_Product_Interest__c}"
var sourceValue="{!Lead.LeadSource}"
var descriptionValue="{!Lead.Description}"
var recordTypeValue='0126C000000L4r3'
var phoneValue="{!Lead.Phone}"
var detailValue="{!Lead.Lead_Source_Detail__c}"
var refContactId="{!Lead.Referral_Contact_ID__c}"
window.location='/'+'a07'+'/e'+'?'+ LeadIdValue +'RecordType='+recordTypeValue+'&CF00N30000000lf9m_lkid='+ LeadIdValue+'&00N30000000mGRj='+NameValue+'&00N30000000lf5c='+MailValue+'&00N30000000lf5V='+CompanyValue+'&00N30000000lf6T='+sInterest+'&00N30000000lf5k='+pInterest+'&00N30000000lf5Y='+phoneValue+'&00N30000000lf70='+descriptionValue+'&00N30000000lf5g='+sourceValue+'&00N80000005EqVW='+detailValue+'&CF00N30000000lf9l_lkid'+refContactId
```

Comment: You can use the JS `encodeURIComponent()` function: `var LeadIdValue=encodeURIComponent("{!Lead.Id}");`. Documentation on that function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Oh and you're missing an `&`, change `window.location='/'+'a07'+'/e'+'?'+ LeadIdValue +'RecordType='` to `window.location='/'+'a07'+'/e'+'?'+ LeadIdValue +'&RecordType='`

Comment: If is used encodeURIComponent where to decode those fields as It  is directly to be populated in other custom object through URL and URL doesnt allow &

Comment: It should be decoded automatically by Salesforce when the page gets loaded.